how to put borders in Android studio?
I would like to know if there is a normal way to display borders in a table in Android studio in the last versions.
i have checked some post before that u can display, but it seems like a little bit stupid that u can´t access border properties from the attributes.
Is there a easy way to do it? should i use grid view instead of table layout?
Thank you so much for answering
I have read this post and i,m doing this at the moment, want to know if there is a better way so solve this question.
border-for-table-row-items-in-android
